# Issues with hiding <tr> elements in sharepoint form using jquery

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, hide-elements

I'm running into issue trying to hide  elements in my sharepoint NewForm.

I've added the jquery script to my NewForm

`<script src="/SiteScripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>`

I have two types of  elements

`<tr class="EventRow">`

`<tr class="ActivityRow">`

I'm trying to hide and show this specific rows when a radiobutton is checked.

I've tried `$('.EventRow').hide()` and recived the following error from IE and FireFox

IE

> Object doesn't support property or method 'hide'

FF

> TypeError: $(...).hide is not a function

How can I hide a  element on a sharepoint form?

Comment: you need to load jquery, not jqueryui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.hide is part of the jQuery framework. Loading jQueryUI won't give you that function.

```
//Load jQuery first
<script src="/SiteScripts/jquery.js"></script>
//Then jQueryUI
<script src="/SiteScripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why it didn't worked using `hide`. One problem might be the script is getting executed prior the table gets loaded.

Here is another way to do the same

```
$('.EventRow').css("display", "none");
```